# Optimizing Xcode Build time when using Firebase library

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Since I'm building using FireStore and few other Firebase library, the build time has doubled down. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid compiling it every time I clean & build my project.

Comment: How do you manage the libraries? Adding frameworks (available) using Carthage can be an option to avoid building them each time, instead of CocoaPods.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk I though about that, but Carthage to much of a learning curve, I can’t impose that to the whole team

Comment: @omerfarukozturk And yes im using cocoapods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this post, we finally found a way to optimize **Firestore** build time while still using cocoapods.

We are using [THIS REPO](https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks)

It's a precompiled Firestore iOS SDK xcframework files extracted from the `Firebase iOS SDK` repository release downloads, tagged by `Firebase iOS SDK` version and presented as a consumable *podspec*.

**Why**

Currently the `Firestore iOS SDK` depends on some **500k lines of mostly C++**, which when compiling as part of your Xcode build takes a long time - even more so in CI environments.

Answer (score 4):

Don't clean & build, just build. ;)

*Disclaimer: Before doing releases, a clean build is preferred, of course.*

---

**UPDATE with better answer: Use `cocoapods-binary` plugin.**

https://guides.cocoapods.org/plugins/pre-compiling-dependencies.html

> One solution for this is to not give Xcode the chance to re-compile code. CocoaPods Binary will pre-compile your Pods during pod install, and then add the binary assets (e.g. .framework files) into the generated Xcode projects instead of the source code.

Like this.

```
plugin 'cocoapods-binary'
use_frameworks!

target "MyApp" do
  pod "NeededPod", :binary => true
end
```

Comment: Haven't though about that, you're a genius

Comment: Haha, I really was trying to help. I was thinking, maybe you have this habit to always clean and build during development, which doesn't lead to much more compile time in a small project. @Jaythaking

Comment: I'm getting this error: `target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries`

Comment: Seems like this cannot be used when I have many external pod using Firebase as well...

Comment: where to put this code snippet?

Comment: In your Podfile @IceFire